# Why is _REQUEST["MAX_FILE_SIZE"] set to 2097152?

Tags: php

I have been following this very simple PHP upload script:

http://www.commentcamarche.net/faq/889-php-upload-de-fichiers

I did check that:

```
$ cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep upload_max_filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2047M
```

and

```
$ cat /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini | grep post_max_size
post_max_size = 2146445312 ; 2047M + 10K
```

However nomatter what I set in my form the hard limit is always (using phpinfo() to display info):

```
           Core
  PHP Version   5.3.3-7+squeeze14 
  post_max_size 2146445312  2146445312
  upload_max_filesize   2047M   2047M

           PHP Variables
  _REQUEST["MAX_FILE_SIZE"] 2097152
  _POST["MAX_FILE_SIZE"]    2097152
```

Where is this limit possible coming from ? All I need is a simple HTML form to send data, since my customer is not capable of my anonymous ftp upload.

For completeness here is what I use:

```
$ cat input.html
<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2012345">
          <input type="file" name="nom_du_fichier">    
          <input type="submit" value="Envoyer">    
</form>
```

I even tried removing the field MAX_FILE_SIZE, it never change. I used the magic value 2012345 in the hope to see it appear in the output of phpinfo() but again with no luck so far...

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have set an hidden input named MAX_FILE_SIZE, like in the commentcamarche website ?

Comment: Yes, I set is as: <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2012345"> (some kind of magic number to recognize it in phpinfo() output but it never shows up, MAX_FILE_SIZE is always 2097152)

Comment: What happen if you remove this input ? (ps: can you post the code of your form ?)

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making those changes to php.ini?